# CodeQL -Error: init post-action step failed: Error: Config file could not be found at expected location. Did the 'init' action fail to start?

Tags: javascript, next.js, github-actions, codeql

I'm working on the NEXT.js app and I got this error, What is the reason for that? I happened When I check the code with :

*CodeQL / Analyze (javascript) (pull_request) Failing after 13s — Analyze (javascript)*

My Error is :
***Error: init post-action step failed: Error: Config file could not be found at expected location. Did the 'init' action fail to start?***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking, my problem happens because of the repo is in a private state. We put them as public.

Comment: The error is that your configuration file was not found. Are you using a code-scanning config file? What is the path to it in your repository? And can you include your code scanning workflow?